# Make python file that isn't reliant on installed packages

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a python.py file that I would like to by able to run on any computer that has python installed.

However, the program uses several packages that I installed through pip (BeautifulSoup and Selenium).

Is there a way to make a single python file that will automatically incorporate everything it needs from these packages into the .py file?

Thanks!

Comment: nope, since f.ex. bs depends on lxml, which is c-extension, and either compiled or installed from binaries. you'd better add dependencies to your setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nice solution to do this. It would be the best to use existing mechanisms -- as dependencies defined in `setup.py`.

If you really need to do this, you could execute the corresponding scripts using `subprocess.call()`:

1. Check whether `pip` is available. If not, terminate the program.
2. Check whether `virtualenv` is available. If yes, create and activate a new environment.
3. Call `pip` to install the required packages.

If `virtualenv` is not installed, this will require root privileges.